# Azure Logic App SMTP error Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create SMTP connection in my Azure Logic App. I got SMTP server address, port and email, and it doesn't require any password.But I am getting below error

> Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again.
> Details: BadGateway More diagnostic information:
> x-ms-client-request-id is

Is there anything wrong with Azure account and how to fix it. Also where I can find this Dignostic information in logic app? I have checked SMTP details locally and it works so It should work in Azure logic app as well.

Comment: I think bad gateway indicates that the SMTP server is not reached. Does the SMTP server have IP-restrictions? You may need to enable the Logic App IP-range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with @ Jokkeri sometimes generally SMTP Bad Gateway appears due to Ip restrictions and firewall rules blocking the connection.

- As shown in below image getting the same error here i am getting this error because of invalid SMTP credentials. So once check with all your SMTP connection details like server address and port number.
  [image]
- Also verify that the Logic App has the right access rights to the SMTP server. This may entail setting up firewall rules or adding the IP address of the Logic App to a whitelist. so once verify whether any firewall rules are preventing the Azure Logic App from connecting to the SMTP server.

> For this question Also where I can find this Dignostic information in logic app...?

- As shown in below images go to Diagnose and solve problems  there you can select performance trouble shoot or Connector Health trouble shoot.
  [image]
- Here i am selecting connector health and as shown in below copied the error message then we will get error related information.
  [image]
  In this way you can find Diagnose information.
- Other way for Diagnose information after workflow run is Go to the Logic App that is having trouble by opening the Azure interface and selecting it.
  Select "Runs history" from the menu.
- Click on the run that caused the error after locating it.
- Then click the "Diagnose and solve problems" button in the "Run details" tab.
- By doing so, the "Diagnostic tools" pane will open, allowing you to inspect the run's diagnostic details, including the x-ms-client-request-id.

Reference MS [document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/448724/unable-to-send-email-using-smtp-email-in-azure-log),MS [document 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53937051/azure-logic-app-502-bad-gateway-error?rq=1) question.

Comment: Yes, issue was with the firewall rule.